# Break or Continue Implemented?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

Does the for/foreach loops in ant-contrib support the equivalent of a "break" or "continue" statement?  As far as I can tell, they do not.

Are there any viable work-arounds?

Thanks
-T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way to implement this behavior, but maybe the following suggestion will help.

- use the the [`for` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) (i.e. not the foreach)
- set the `keepgoing` attribute to true
- use the [`fail` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) with a condition so that the items that need to be skipped will fail.

---

you can obtain something like a *break* by defining a property `myBreakProperty` whenever you detect that you need to break

```
 <for list="a,b,c,d,e" param="letter" keepgoing="true">
    <sequential>
       <if>
         <equals arg1="@{letter}" arg2="c" />
       <then>
         <property name="myBreakProperty" value="nevermind the value"/>
       </then>
     </if>
     <fail if="myBreakProperty"/>
     <echo>Letter @{letter}</echo>
    </sequential>
 </for>
```

The output will be:  `Letter a Letter b`

---

To obtain something like a *continue* :

```
 <for list="a,b,c,d,e" param="letter" keepgoing="true">
    <sequential>
       <if>
         <equals arg1="@{letter}" arg2="c" />
       <then>
         <fail/>
       </then>
     </if>
     <echo>Letter @{letter}</echo>
    </sequential>
 </for>
```

The output will be:  `Letter a Letter b Letter d Letter e`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a break process flow without running something as harsh as a fail.  Using a property to detect when you want to break you can implement something like this:

```
<var name="break.flag" unset="true"/>

<for list="a,b,c,d,e" param="letter">
    <sequential>
        <if>
            <not>
                <isset property="break.flag"/>
            </not>
        <then>
            <if>
                <equals arg1="@{letter}" arg2="c" />
            <then>
                <property name="break.flag" value="true"/>
            </then>
            </if>

            <if>
                <not>
                    <isset property="break.flag"/>
                </not>
            <then>
                <echo>Letter @{letter}</echo>
                <echo>Do the rest of the loop here</echo>
            </then>
            </if>
        </then>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: Your code does not work, you need to unset the flag if it hits

Answer (score 0):

To really break the loop you could use fail together with trycatch

```
            <trycatch>
                <try>
                    <for param="i" begin="1" end="99">
                        <sequential>
                            ...
                            <fail message="break" />
                        </sequential>
                    </for>
                </try>
                <catch />
            </trycatch>
```